# Elixir doesn't minify and combine

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

hello im trying to minify and combine my files to one js and css file but its not working when i run gulp --production my gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
     /**
     * Copy needed files from /node directories
     * to /public directory.
     */
    mix.copy(
       'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
       'public/build/fonts/font-awesome'
     )
    mix.copy(
       'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap',
       'public/build/fonts/bootstrap'
     )
    mix.copy(
       'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js',
       'public/js/vendor/bootstrap'
     )

    mix.styles(['frontend.css', 'style.css', 'responsive.css'], 'public/build/css/frontend.css', 'public/css')
    .styles(['backend.css'], 'public/build/css/backend.css', 'public/css');
    mix.scripts(['frontend.js'], 'public/build/js/frontend.js' , 'public/js')
    .scripts(['backend.js'], 'public/build/js/backend.js', 'public/js');

    mix.version(["public/css/frontend.css", "public/js/frontend.js", "public/css/backend.css", "public/js/backend.js"]);
});
```

and my console output

```
➜  public_html gulp --production
[19:29:22] Using gulpfile /home/admin/web/***.com/public_html/gulpfile.js
[19:29:22] Starting 'default'...
[19:29:22] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*


Saving To...
   - public/build/fonts/font-awesome

[19:29:22] Finished 'default' after 49 ms
[19:29:22] Finished 'copy' after 80 ms
[19:29:22] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/**/*


Saving To...
   - public/build/fonts/bootstrap

[19:29:22] Finished 'copy' after 8.26 ms
[19:29:22] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/vendor/bootstrap

[19:29:22] Finished 'copy' after 3.33 ms
[19:29:22] Starting 'styles'...

Fetching Styles Source Files...
   - public/css/frontend.css
   - public/css/style.css
   - public/css/responsive.css


Saving To...
   - public/build/css/frontend.css

[19:29:29] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Stylesheets Merged!
[19:29:29] Finished 'styles' after 7.12 s
[19:29:29] Starting 'styles'...

Fetching Styles Source Files...
   - public/css/backend.css


Saving To...
   - public/build/css/backend.css

[19:29:40] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Stylesheets Merged!
[19:29:40] Finished 'styles' after 11 s
[19:29:40] Starting 'scripts'...

Fetching Scripts Source Files...
   - public/js/frontend.js


Saving To...
   - public/build/js/frontend.js

[19:29:40] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged!
[19:29:40] Finished 'scripts' after 866 ms
[19:29:40] Starting 'scripts'...

Fetching Scripts Source Files...
   - public/js/backend.js


Saving To...
   - public/build/js/backend.js

[19:29:41] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged!
[19:29:41] Finished 'scripts' after 610 ms
[19:29:41] Starting 'version'...

Fetching Version Source Files...
   - public/css/frontend.css
   - public/js/frontend.js
   - public/css/backend.css
   - public/js/backend.js


Saving To...
   - public/build

[19:29:41] Finished 'version' after 52 ms
```

basically it should minify and combine css and js files in to one css and js file

but style.css and responsive.css are not combined in frontend.css file

pls help what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you are versioning the wrong files. you need to version the files in your build folder public/build/...

Generally, as a 'good practice' to stop things like this happening, the result of combining styles/js files should not have the same name as one of the component parts. This issue has been caused by naming one of the input files frontend.css as well as the output file frontend.css. it's better if you use something like all.css or app.css for the output file